# I can not change a dataframe column name because it has Double Quotation mark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to work with pandas and I can not change a dataframe column name because it has Double Quotation mark and df.rename() it only changes the columns that doesn't have double Quotation [pic of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm0GQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would put your code in text format.

You can set/rename columns using `df.columns = [column_list]`

Comment: Thank you for your help